# Can anyone explain briefly on what does 'ovm_do_with actually does?

Tags: sequence, uvm

I'm new to OVM and Saola. Can anyone explain what does

`'ovm_do_with(a,{b=0})` actually does?

Comment: I only know about UVM, not OVM. I would imagine my answer is valid for OVM as well as UVM given the similarity, but you need to check this.

Answer (score 0):

```
`uvm_do_with(req, CONSTRAINT)
```

is a *macro*. It expands to

```
req = tx_type::type_id::create("req");
start_item(req);
if( !req.randomize() with CONSTRAINT ) `uvm_error(...)
finish_item(req);
```

So

```
'ovm_do_with(a,{b=0})
```

expands to

```
a = tx_type::type_id::create("a");
start_item(a);
if( !a.randomize() with {b=0}) `uvm_error(...)
finish_item(a);
```